# Using wso2mb message broker server with a php client

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, php-amqplib, php-amqp

I trying to connect a php client (using [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) lib) to a server based on wso2mb (wso2 message broker version 3.1.0).

I couldnt succed in that when using the amqp_consumer.php and always locked with this error :

INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Unable to create SASL Server:AMQPLAIN whilst processing:[ConnectionStartOkBodyImpl: clientProperties={product=[LONG_STRING: AMQPLib], platform=[LONG_STRING: PHP], version=[LONG_STRING: 2.6], information=[LONG_STRING: ], copyright=[LONG_STRING: ], capabilities=[FIELD_TABLE: {authentication_failure_close=[BOOLEAN: true], publisher_confirms=[BOOLEAN: true], consumer_cancel_notify=[BOOLEAN: true], exchange_exchange_bindings=[BOOLEAN: true], basic.nack=[BOOLEAN: true], connection.blocked=[BOOLEAN: true]}]}, mechanism=AMQPLAIN, response=[5, 76, 79, 71, 73, 78, 83, 0, 0, 0, 5, 97, 100, 109, 105, 110, 8, 80, 65, 83, 83, 87, 79, 82, 68, 83, 0, 0, 0, 5, 97, 100, 109, 105, 110], locale=en_US]
[2016-11-04 08:05:26,901]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Closing connection due to: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionException: Unable to create SASL Server:AMQPLAIN [error code 506: resource error]

I using thos params in confing.php as conexions params

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 5692);
define('USER', 'admin');
define('PASS', 'admin');
define('VHOST', '/');
```

My questions :
1. Could you recommand any php library / tutorial to establish communication between some php code and wso2mb ?
2. What are the connexion method that are allowed by wso2mb ? (PLAIN, AMQPLAIN...?)
3. Help plz :)

Comment: Okey, the php-amqp is design to work with RabbitMQ. Switched to RabbitMQ and everything is Okey.

Comment: Although tested mostly with RabbitMQ, AMQPlib is theoretically talking a standardised protocol, which WSO2 MB claims to also talk, so it would be good to know why this didn't work. It seems like an authentication error, since SASL is presumably [Simple Authentication and Security Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer).

Comment: Could you try changing define('VHOST', '/'); to define('VHOST', 'carbon');? Because WSO2 MB default virtualhost name is 'carbon'.